# react is displaying only the last item in the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
renderItems(game){

    if (game.category_id === 2) {
        ownedGames.map((owned_game) => {
            if (owned_game.game_id === game.game_id) {
                renderPriceSection = renderOwned
                console.log(owned_game.game_title)
            } else {
                renderPriceSection = renderPrice
            }
        })
    } else {
        renderPriceSection = renderFreeToPlayTitle
    }

}
...
return(
    {renderPriceSection}
)
```

I'm trying to display some labels: `Owned`, `$Price`, `Free`

The `console.log` is displaying all the correct games that should have the `Owned` label.

But, on the page, the `Owned` label is **ONLY showing up for the last item** in the `owned_games` array.

Any idea why this is happening?

---

**Edit:**

I removed the `renderItems()` function and replaced `{renderPriceSection}` with this:

```
    {game.category_id === 2 ?
        ownedGames.map(owned_game =>
            owned_game.game_id === game.game_id ? renderOwned : renderPrice
        ) :
        renderFreeToPlayTitle
    }
```

Now the `renderOwned` and `renderPrice` is being displayed `owned_games.length` times for each item.
So now i'm on the oposite side of the wrong output :)))

Comment: It happens because renderPriceSection is getting overwritten on every map iteration. Also this isn't a right way to use map, map returns an array and if you show what your array looks like and what is your expected output perhaps we can help better

Comment: Since the label is only being displayed for the last item, i was thinking the same thing. That it's overwriting it. But can't think of a better way to do this.

Comment: I'm using `map` instead of a for loop i guess. I updated the question.

Comment: What is the expected output for this code, what is it that you are getting, i mean in what way is it different?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are modifying the same reference of `renderPriceSection` on every other iteration you are changing the same object, you are not creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map` returns another array. It seems you are not returning anything inside your `map` function. Also, it's not clear what `renderPriceSelection` is supposed to be.

```
renderPriceSelection = ownedGames.map((owned_game) => {
  if (owned_game.game_id === game.game_id) {
    return renderOwned
  } else {
    return renderPrice
  }
})

render {renderPriceSelection}
```

Comment: `renderPriceSection` is just a final valriable that will render either the price, the free or the owned label. I'm trying to reproduce at a very small scale.

Comment: Use the map similar the way I described then and `console.log(renderPriceSelection)` to check whether this is what you want or not.

Answer (score 0):

From this code it's not entirely clear, but it seems to me that you rewrite the variable renderPriceSection at each iteration, and that's why renderItems returns the last element each time

Answer (score 0):

You store the **renderPriceSelection in form of an array** like below, and then render this array when you are returning values from this given function, here i have returned as list elements. Hope it helps.

```
renderItems(game){

    renderPriceSection = [];

    if (game.category_id === 2) {
     ownedGames.map((owned_game) => {
        if (owned_game.game_id === game.game_id) {
            renderPriceSection.push(renderOwned);
            console.log(owned_game.game_title)
        } else {
            renderPriceSection.push(renderPrice);
        }
      })
   } else {
      renderPriceSection.push(renderFreeToPlayTitle);
  }

}

 ...
 return(
    <ul>
       {renderPriceSection.map((eachPrice) => <li>eachPrice</li>)}
    </ul>
)
```